# how to run javascript when sql has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using some github jquery code https://github.com/viralpatel/jquery.shorten to automatically shorten a paragraph and add a read more button, so i made the div element and it works fine when i use normal text, but i tried to add some sql (inside php) to show a value of something in a sql table, but when i load the page it just says "more" and when i click it, it loads the value from the sql, but it is supposed to just shrink the value and then when you click more it is supposed to show the rest instead it shows nothing and then when you click "more" it shows all of it, I am really stuck on this, have been trying to find an answer already for a few days.

example code

```
<div class="example">
    <?php echo $sql_query; ?>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".example").shorten({showChars: 100});
     });
</script>
```

Comment: please post some example code in order to understand better

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia is that good?

Comment: yes but instead of "<?php echo $sql_query; ?>" what there should be if wee have a look to the generated page?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia it is near the top of the body

Comment: yes but i mean, from this script "<?php echo $sql_query; ?>" what can be a possible string to use to test? like a string long 1123124 chars or what?

Comment: it works perfectly on my pc this code...

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia make sure the variable $sql_query is longer than 100 characters  and make sure you are loading it from a sql database, otherwise it will work perfectly if it is just a normal variable

Comment: i've added a lorem ipsum of 180 words, and from where the string comes from, for jquery does not matter, please post the string you are using or getting from the database

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia put the lorem ipsum into a database and then connect to it and retrieve it from the database and assign it to the variable of `$sql_query` and then try run it, that is what i am doing

Comment: it does not matter, PHP is a thing, JQuery is another thing, PHP runs on Server, JQuery on the front end, so when JQuery get that string, it can't know where that string comes from... please, post the String you are getting from the database

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I know that but it takes a few milliseconds extra for the php to get it from the database, that is the problem  I just tried it with Lorem ipsum  and the same thing happens, it is because the script runs as while the page is loading and it doesn't see anything in the div because that only gets loaded a few milliseconds later

Comment: if instead of "<?php echo $sql_query; ?>" you write "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam omnis dolorum nihil id reprehenderit, assumenda aperiam rerum quas nemo voluptates. Accusantium sapiente optio atque aspernatur aut ducimus veritatis laudantium sequi ratione veniam. Impedit porro deserunt dolorem consectetur commodi sunt, quae odit illum culpa suscipit at vel ad accusantium omnis a recusandae debitis reprehenderit incidunt quibusdam? Porro laborum labore consectetur adipisci dolorum eligendi, cupiditate quisquam quos tenetur incidunt qui dolor" it works?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it was causing such problems, I had comments inside the div element before the php echo, so it was counting the comments as chars, so when i removed the comments it all worked.